# How can I reduce the hardcoded part in React Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Here is the hardcoded part:

```
const filtersInfo = [
        {
            resetValue: props.setClass,
            valueInfo: classValue && <p>Class: {classes.find(c => c.slug === classValue).name} x</p>
        },
        {
            resetValue: props.resetManaCost,
            valueInfo: manaCostBar && <p>Mana : {manaCostBar} x</p>
        },
        {
            resetValue: props.setTextFilter,
            valueInfo: textFilter && <p>{textFilter} x</p>
        },
//10 more items
]
```

Then I just iterate through it:

```
const filterItems = filtersInfo.map((f, i) => <SimpleInfo key={i} resetValue={f.resetValue} valueInfo={f.valueInfo} />)
```

How can I reduce this hardcoding? I guess I should put it in my Redux store but each part depends on different reducer and it would be a mess to do it.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you mean by hardcoded here. Moving it to redux wouldn't change its "harcodedness". If you load data from a database, then you use variables which replace the hardcoded values, but it doesn't look like the stuff you are talking about is dynamic data. or is it?

Comment: I just need to make my component less dirty and yes it is dynamic

Comment: `I just need to make my component less dirty` <-- this is bad thinking. anyways, I think we need to see more code. I don't see anything that could be considered "dirty"